# Angular application works on Chrome but not Safari

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, safari

My website works fine on Chrome but is broken on Apple Mobile Safari.

I have troubleshot the situation and have found that it is the below line of code placed in side of my angular controller that is causing the problem. With out this code everything works fine.

The code takes all images on the page and puts them inside of an array. Anything I can do differently to ensure proper compatibility? Thank you!

```
$scope.load_picture_cotent = function () {

  $scope.pictures = Array.from(

    document.querySelectorAll
    ('div.album [style^="background-image"]')).map
    (el=>el.style.backgroundImage.replace(/url\((.*)\)/,'$1')
          .replace(/"/g,'')
          .replace(/thumbnails/,'highresolution'));

    console.log($scope.pictures);
}
```

You can also view the website [here](http://kiawahislandgetaways.com/codingFun/KarlyPortfolio/route-test/index.html#/home).

Please let me know if you need any more information or would like me to expand my post to include more information.

Comment: How is it broken?

Comment: The application doesn't start. My website uses Angular route (with the menu bar and footer as part of the index.html and the content being imported using route.) The header and footer loads but the angular JS route does not display the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using ECMA 2015 lambda notation, try to wrap this with babel and try it again, did you check the browsers compatibility status with ECMA Script 2015?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you bretanac93.

He was right, I was using a newer version of Javascript than is currently supported by browsers.

He recommended I use Babel which is a compiler that converts new Javascript to a compatible Javascript.

I used [babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=) to compile the compatibility javascript and it works like a charm.